# Unrelated Laravel console command run

Tags: laravel, console, command

When I run a console command for example `sudo -u www-data php artisan logger:logSomethingImportant` I noticed that it was much slower than usual. I debugged it and discovered that the constructor functions of other console commands are run (I have a DB lookup which times out which caused the delay). Is it normal, that totally unrelated commands are fired (well at least the constructor function is run)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since command signatures in Laravel are stored inside command classes, how else would artisan know if what you're running matches this or that signature? Hence it's completely normal that constructors are called; you could just move your code into an `init()` method and call it only when the command is run.